# Grok debugging issue with double space

Tags: logstash-grok

I have the following log which was generated using log4net

```
2017-12-11 17:01:28,390 [6] INFO  DAL.DBManager "FunctionName":"Dispose"
```

The problem is the 2 spaces after INFO.  If the word is debug it seems to only have 1 space, so it could be "tab".

I'm using http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ but my pattern, below,  doesn't seem to work.

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601} \[%{NUMBER:thread}\] %{LOGLEVEL:log-level} %{DATA:CLASS} %{DATA:Function} %{DATA:FunctionName} %{GREEDYDATA:remainder}
```

I've tried adding %{SPACE} instead of the space but it doesn't generate anything.

Comment: Did my answer help to solve your question?

Comment: I wasn't aware of ( )? before.  Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match exactly two whitespaces, you'll have to add two whitespaces in your pattern aswell. Following pattern seems to match the line you wrote:

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601} \[%{NUMBER:thread}\] %{LOGLEVEL:log-level}  %{DATA:CLASS}\.%{DATA:Function} %{DATA:FunctionName}\:%{GREEDYDATA:remainder}
```

---

If you want to match one or two whitespaces you can use a whitespace and an optional whitespace `( )?` like so:

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601} \[%{NUMBER:thread}\] %{LOGLEVEL:log-level} ( )?%{DATA:CLASS}\.%{DATA:Function} %{DATA:FunctionName}\:%{GREEDYDATA:remainder}
```